# Trouble with vue.js to get data from REST API

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to get data from a rest api using vue.js. But it's not working. It neither show response data nor showing error status. Can't figure it out what went wrong.

Here's my `index.html`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

        <div id="app">
            {{ message }}
        </div>

        <script>
            var url = "http://clients.itsd.com.bd/table-cartel/wp-json/wp/v2/categories";
            var app = new Vue({
                el: "#app",
                data: {
                    message: "Hello!"
                },
                methods: {
                    work: function(){
                        alert(url);
                        this.$http.get(url).then(function(response){
                            alert(response.data);
                            this.message = response.data;
                        }, function(error){
                            alert(error.statusText);
                        });
                    }
                },
                mounted: function(){
                    this.work();
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's showing `url`, but not showing `response.data` or `error.statusText`.

I followed the process described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40069998/3968623).

Comment: You should use a HTTP client package like [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) or [vue-resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource). Vue does not include one by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are missing `vue-resource`. 
Also include this dependency:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-resource"></script>
```

And before creating the vue instance, paste this:

```
Vue.use(VueResource)
```

Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DarkFruits/euv04n9d/

Comment: it's not working. when I'm adding `Vue.use(VueResource)` It's showing `{{ 
message }}` instead of `Hello`. That mean vue stops working. And I'm already using the dependency you mentioned.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar The answer is now updated with the correct script.